# Is there any way I can make a bot that can give roles

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.8

like the title, I need to make a bot that can give roles in a certain format. I have already set up the bot and everything and it can do basic commands. an example of what I want it to do is the following:

```
User: !!roles
Bot:  Who do you want to give roles to?
User: User1 User2 User3 User4     (etc...)
Bot: What role do you want to give them?
User: Admin               (Or rank1 rank2 etc...)
```

Here is my code that I have created (It is a MESS):

```
@client.command(name="roles")
async def _roles(ctx):
  if ctx.message.author.server_permissions.administrator:
    global times_used
    times_used = times_used + 1
    await ctx.send(f"type who you want to give roles to, type cancel to cancel:")

    # This will make sure that the response will only be registered if the following
    # conditions are met:
    def check(msg):
      return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    try:
      msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=120) # 120 seconds to reply

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      await ctx.send("Sorry, you didn't reply in time!")

    if(msg.content == "cancel"):
      return
    else:
      role = get(message.server.roles, name=role_to_give)
      content_split = msg.content.split()
      for user in content_split:
        await client.add_roles(user, role)

  else:
      msg = "You're an average joe {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)  
      await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel, msg)
      return
```

I am using python 3.8.3, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two instances of [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for), one to read the list of users and the other to read the list of roles. 
Also [add_role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add%20role#discord.Member.add_roles) is done on a Member/User object.
For taking multiple instances of a class as an argument you'd find [Greedy](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20greedy#discord.ext.commands.Greedy) useful.